# Issuing http requests from an item pipeline with longer download delays using scrapy

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I would like to use the python web-scraping framework scrapy to download both video meta data and the videos themselves from a video library website and write them to local storage. I don't want to be a nuisance (or risk getting blacklisted!) so I would also like to make use of long download delays. More specifically, I would like long download delays for the big video requests and shorter delays for the meta data requests.

I've been going through the scrapy documentation and it seems sensible to have the video files downloaded as part of an item pipeline. So far I have the meta data for each video clip set to a delay of 5 seconds (using settings.py) and will go through to the meta data pipeline where it gets written locally. The plan is to send the video download url to the video clip pipeline and have the pipeline perform the download with a longer download delay to reduce impact on the source site.

So the questions are:

- Can item pipelines make use of the asynchronous requests and implement delays?
- And if so, can the download_delay setting in settings.py be overidden in the pipeline?

(using scrapy 0.24)

Answer (score 1):

I haven't done this personally but Scrapy devs recommend the [media pipeline](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/blob/master/scrapy/contrib/pipeline/media.py) for this, which [makes use of async requests](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/blob/master/scrapy/contrib/pipeline/media.py#L56). You should be able to [override the settings](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/settings.html#how-to-access-settings) by changing the [`from_crawler`](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/blob/master/scrapy/contrib/pipeline/media.py#L27) method.